# Does ∃x (Px⇔Rx) imply (∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx)?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Does $∃x (Px⇔Rx)$ imply $(∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx)$ ?

I am trying to make an interpretation that verifies $∃x (Px⇔Rx)$ and falsifies $(∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx).$ I have been trying for a while now, and I don't think it is possible.

On the other hand, I do know that $(∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx)$ does not imply $∃x (Px⇔Rx).$

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. How does each statement constrain where values can go?

Comment: ∃x (Px⇔Rx) requires the same element to be of both P and R.  ∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx could be satisfied by having a different elements in both P and R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$∃x\:(Px⇔Rx)\tag1$$ means that some object satisfies either both or neither of $P$ and $R.$

$$∃xPx⇔∃xRx\tag2$$ means that $P$ and $R$ are either each satisfied by some object or each satisfied by no object (i.e., $P$ and $R$ are both either empty or nonempty).

The countermodel

[image]

shows that $$(1)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies(2),$$ while the countermodel

[image]

shows that $$(2)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

∃x (Px⇔Rx) is equivalent to ∃x((-P V R) ^ (-R V P))

∃x((-P V R) ^ (-R V P)) ->  ∃xPx ⇔ ∃xRx is false by counter example

Domain: {0, 1}
P:  {1}
R:  {}

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Counterexample:

Domain: Natural numbers

$P(x): x$ is even

$R(x): x$ is odd